# Solve Forbidden 403 error during response testing

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy, postman

I am trying to get response of website https://clutch.co/sitemap.xml

I tested in Python as well in Postman, it shows a forbidden 403 status code. I copied all of its headers still it doesn't get successful response.

Below is a piece of code snippet I attempted.

```
import requests

headers = {
  'authority': 'clutch.co',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'cookie': 'cf_clearance=mvAUZW1nJug5PB0M8rf93YBwyn4qOdDcU5gy.vVZ6rc-1698494124-0-1-1c669b3c.347dd517.85f5c18c-0.2.1698494124; _ga=GA1.1.1809619058.1698494124; FPID=FPID2.2.pSduR8wDRmNkf3s5Z4HEhBZ18leJVTEtvWiCgKds9tw%3D.1698494124; FPLC=uF%2BpXHT1%2BvYReCd4BPS47IQeM5yO9mB8uwXh95ALGacLDIy4dW%2BByDOe2DeSGiYTq43YZp4EfAPJiXyUnKMJBD52uvoiJDauKzt3M4%2FKxXBfzLunSznieaoZ68xCiA%3D%3D; __cf_bm=tv3SekyYvPpYLykgxBnrp2LtXvkG5Wvh4LFQVrV2_Ks-1698497124-0-AQFsc9n3lMN5iKh+93PrwD1KgyBDNpofby6pZlu3n+02f1WPA84GsHf2Ym6wJARjQ5kokSaz9d9TNsIbP2qMkXQ=; _ga_D0WFGX8X3V=GS1.1.1698494124.1.1.1698497403.56.0.0',
  'if-modified-since': 'Sat, 28 Oct 2023 09:03:15 GMT',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Brave";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'sec-gpc': '1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get('https://clutch.co/sitemap.xml', headers=headers)
```

How do I solve it guys? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If I do it from a browser, the request is served via http2. (https://clutch.co/sitemap.xml HTTP/2.0) - you may want to try asking using this protocol. Look at httpx (https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/) which can to this protocol if you install it.

Answer (score 1):

The site is using cloudflare as prevention from scraping. One solution is to copy your `User-Agent` HTTP header and `__cf_bm` cookie to get result. But beware, the cookie changes frequently!

```py
import requests

url = "https://clutch.co/sitemap.xml"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

cookies = {
    "__cf_bm": "ap_wV732pImoyM_3yvD6TJ7YngLHt6L5xQ0Dm8Qqi50-1698525930-0-ASLsB7CJ9rzp67z8CTqKm6fnmvExRKdmwdWt12XrWcc/J7vfy7GKNvVAP+b0G4Fnxqfcluj1VAHhMVZbeo1KSnU="
}

t = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
print(t)
```

Prints:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd"><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-1.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-2.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-3.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-4.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-5.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-6.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-7.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-8.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-directory-9.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-1.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-2.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-3.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-4.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-5.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-6.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-7.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-8.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-9.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-10.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-11.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-12.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-13.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-14.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-15.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-16.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-17.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-18.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-19.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-20.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-21.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-22.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-23.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-24.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-25.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-26.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-27.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-28.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-29.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-30.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-profile-31.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-standalone.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-articles.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-packages.xml</loc></sitemap><sitemap><loc>https://clutch.co/sitemap-pricing.xml</loc></sitemap></sitemapindex>
```

Comment: I am still unable to get response using this method. I copied the part of cookie as well.
Could you guide on how you got 200 response even with using above method?
From where to where you selected the cookie to be pasted inside?

Comment: @MohitAswani The `User-Agent` needs to be the same as the browser you copied the cookie from. And of course, cloudflare might block you on the IP address  level.

Comment: thank you so much dear Andrej for shed a light onto this topic. BTW: Great to follow you.